# Trying to install metpy in my machine but getting error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-xarray, metpy

Metpy 1.4 got installed but when imported it is showing error even after update

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray.core.accessors'.

I was trying to work with Metpy, although the installation was successful but when I imported it in my code I got

I even tries conda update --all & than conda forge but the things are not working.

Comment: Try installing/updating `xarray`

Comment: Did you do `pip install --upgrade metpy`

Comment: Not enough detail. Please add the output of `conda list '(metpy|xarray)'` to the question body.

Comment: # Name                    Version                   
metpy                     1.4.0              
xarray                    2022.11.0